# Convert Years to decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, decimal, nodatime

I am building an application, and my users are going to need the difference between the current date, and a user's birthdate (in years) to be in decimal format.

---

**UPDATE**

An **exact** example would be this:

> Birthdate - 11/22/1974
>
> Current Date - 02/27/2017
>
> Age = 42.27

---

In my code I am using [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/).

So,

```
var date2 = new LocalDate(emp.DateOfBirth.Year, emp.DateOfBirth.Month, emp.DateOfBirth.Day);

var date1 = new LocalDate(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day);

ViewModelObject.Age = (decimal)Period.Between(date2, date1, PeriodUnits.Years).Years;
```

With the example above.. it will produce `24.00`.. but I need the `.00` to be the actual decimal.

Is there a way to do this?  I don't want the number to rounded.  I need it to be exact.

Comment: You need a specific logic here. First you need to decide how the decimal will look like. Such as if its 24 years and 6 months then should it be 24.5 (0.5 is half of 1) or 24.6 (6 months is half year). Do you consider days also part of decimal?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya see my update, I gave a specific example of what the outcome would be.. 24 years and 6 months would be 24.6

Comment: Given that 24 years and 6 months would be 24.6 I struggle to understand how you arrived at 42.27.

Comment: It would make much more sense to say that the previous birthday was 11/22/2016, the next one is 11/22/2017, which are 365 days apart. Also, there is 97 days between 11/22/2016 and 02/27/2017, so the fraction would be 97/365 ~ 0.2657 ~ 0.27. This fits your example (+ the 42 years of course). But then how 24 years  and 6 months would become 42.6, you sure you understood what the comment asked?

Comment: Then there is the issue of leap years.

Comment: Assuming the syntax is correct ViewModelObject.Age = (decimal)Period.Between(date2, date1, PeriodUnits.Months).Months; would give you the number of months. Then you could use (numberOfMonths/12) for the year part and the mod of numberOfMonths and 12 to get the decimal part. You could use similar logic using to find the number of days and only deal with the mod of the days relevant to the months in the two dates.

Comment: Period.Years returns a `long` , so that is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: The best answer would probably be the number of days divided by 365.25

Comment: Yes, but even 365.25 is an approximation. When you need a very accurate number for children you may need some better rules.

Comment: I think you should write down a set of testcases for yourself and then work your way towards a solution that way. For instance, given that a person is born on february 29th in a leap year, how old is that person on the 28th next year? Or 1st of march next year? Do day-by-day that span the 29th of february in a leap year contribute slightly less to the fraction than when it doesn't span a leap year?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid, if 24 years and 6 month is 24.6, 24 years and 11 month is 24.11? (as a decimal, this is lower than 24.6) What about 24 years and 10 months, vs 24 years and 1 month? you are expecting that 24.10 and 24.1 have different meanings? You need to define a meaningful logic before trying to implement it

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen sorry for the delay, I was on my way home.. but all of your comments are on point.. and honestly I do not have an answer for 'how specific' this should be.  The current user doing this, is pulling from Microsoft Access.  I don't know if that person has a custom formula or if Access does that automatically when subtracting dates. If you want, I can ask that person tomorrow and update my question if they have any extra info.  Otherwise I was just hoping for a standard formula to convert dates to decimals.

Comment: In principle, it is impossible for there to be a standard formula. You must find out what the age is being used for (biology, age of majority, how much to charge for life insurance, eligibility for pension benefits, etc.). Then you must find the exact rules for the use, including every special case, such as being born on February 29 or having one's birthdate recorded in Greece when the Julian calendar was in effect. Then you must write code that exactly implements the rules you have discovered.

Comment: Completely agree with the comments here - you really need to work out *exactly* what your requirements are. Hopefully at that point Noda Time will make it easy to fulfil those requirements, but you do need to be really careful here. Calendrical arithmetic is hard even before you try to bring floating point arithmetic into it...

Comment: The thing to keep in mind here is that Years, Months, and Days are *variable* units of measure with respect to time.  One cannot say precisely how many days have elapsed in "5 years".  One has to know *which* five years.  Decimal math is nonsensical here.  Averages only get you so far.  Also obligatory: http://codeofmatt.com/2014/04/09/handling-birthdays-and-other-anniversaries/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
ViewModelObject.Age = (decimal) ((dateNow - dateOfBirth).TotalDays / 365.25);
```

For a persons age there are basically 2 systems:

- calendar based. The age is an integer based on the y/m/d values and common sense or legal rules. The length of the months (28/30/31) is ignored, leap days are rolled over. The notion of fractional years or days is not supported.
- biomedical or statistical. Usually computed based on days/365.25. This will only give you an approximation, it may differ from the legal definition on anniversaries.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible that this could generate an age that is slightly too low even if you check on the exact date, or slightly too high if you check on the date before the birthday? (ie. rounding errors round down so instead of being exactly 42 years on your birthday you're 41.9999something, or instead of being 41.99999something on the day before your birthday you're 42.something)

Comment: And that is exactly what this formula will do. I'm born on the 23rd of february 1971, if you input that + the date 23rd of february 2020 and see how old I am you will see that your formula outputs 48.99931something whereas it should at least output 49. I'm afraid it isn't this easy. But yes, how to deal with leap years is a very valid question to the OP.

Comment: When you ask for an age in decimals you want (should accept) normal rounding rules. There are much bigger errors for small children born near a leap day. Do note that I left the rounding to 2 decimals up to the View, your sample would show up as 49.0

Comment: We have no idea what this application is going to be used for and if you turn up to buy beer on your 18th birthday in norway and is refused because the cash register claims you're 17.999 years old it is probably a rounding error you can't accept. At the very least I would ask the OP to specify some rules dictating leap years and how accurate this should be.

Comment: Lasse, I agree that this is not sufficient for legal purposes. But I've seen this often enough in statistical applications to assume a 'normal' here. If the OP was doing a government app he would have better specs already.

Comment: @HenkHolterman sorry for the delay, I was on my way home.. but all of your comments are on point.. and honestly I do not have an answer for 'how specific' this should be. The current user doing this, is pulling from Microsoft Access. I don't know if that person has a custom formula or if Access does that automatically when subtracting dates. If you want, I can ask that person tomorrow and update my question if they have any extra info. Otherwise I was just hoping for a standard formula to convert dates to decimals. I can test this tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: So the next leap year is Feb. 29th, 2020.  So I did this: [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eK9Xc8).. should the 2 decimal places be the same as today's?

Comment: Checked the dotnetfiddle code. If birthdate is 2016-02-29 it calculates age as 4 years for both 2020-03-01 and 2020-02-28.  And as 5 years for both 2021-03-01 and 2021-02-28. The same with other dates too. Two consicutive target dates gives the same output.

Comment: I tested the code in dotnetfiddle link shared by OP by putting various values in mydate and today variables.

And I believe it uses two decimal points to display the result. Not sure what did I miss.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I missed that.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid - you picked 2 decimals, that's about 3.6 days worth of accuracy...  What is 'right' depends solely on what you need it for...  You haven't told us yet.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just checked with my user, and what you provided is perfect.  thank you.